# 'GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, google-authentication

Onload I have the code below called:

```
import {GoogleSignin} from 'react-native-google-signin';
console.log(GoogleSignin)
GoogleSignin.configure({
  iosClientId: <GoogleClientID>,
})
```

Immediately the app errors out and returns -
`Cannot read property configure of undefined`.
I traced the error back to the `GoogleSignin.ios.js` file inside the react-native-google-signin npm folder. The line the error eventually points to is as follows - 
`const { RNGoogleSignin } = NativeModules;` saying that `RNGoogleSignin` is undefined.

I'm assuming this must be a NativeModules issue since `RNGoogleSignin` is supposed to be deconstructed from there. I followed all the steps according to the iOS and Google OAuth Docs, but I'm still not sure what the issue is.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried rebuild your native code?

If you add some package relative native code, you need `link` and rebuild native code.